# How to determine the winner by validate prediction with actual score

Tags: php, conditional-statements

To find out what the result/score is of a prediction I need to validate/process the prediction with the actual score of the soccermatch.

I will assign the following amount of points to a result of a prediction.

- 10 points: correct prediction
- **5 points: winner/draw prediction correct**
- 2 points: score prediction home-team correct
- 2 points: score prediction away-team correct

To validate the correct prediction was not that difficult ;-)
I'm struggling at the moment how to validate the winner of a game?

**Question: How do I validate the winner of a game based on the actual score and how do I validate this with the prediction of this game?**

Below the piece of code where I started the validation, is this the correct way?

```php
for ($i=0;$i<$arrQueryUitslag["number_of_rows"];$i++)
{
    $intPoints = 0;

    $IntHomeScore = $arrQueryUitslag[$i]['home_score'];
    $IntAwayScore = $arrQueryUitslag[$i]['away_score'];
    $IntHomePrediction = $arrQueryUitslag[$i]['home_prediction'];
    $IntAwayPrediction = $arrQueryUitslag[$i]['away_prediction'];

    //prediction is correct
    if (($IntHomeScore == $IntHomePrediction) && ($IntAwayScore == $IntAwayPrediction))
    {
        $intPoints = 10;
    }
    //one part of prediction is correct
    elseif ((($IntHomeScore == $IntHomePrediction) && ($IntAwayScore != $IntAwayPrediction)) || (($IntHomeScore != $IntHomePrediction) && ($IntAwayScore == $IntAwayPrediction)))
    {
        $intPoints = 2;
    }

    //Update of insert query om scores te op te slaan in db.

}
```

Comment: Since we have no idea what you're trying to accomplish because we don't have enough detail we would have to get out our crystal balls to make sure this is the "correct way".

Comment: This seems to implement part of the scoring you layed out. What is your actual question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically correct. For the 5 points question just add an elseif before your elseif with this code:

```
elseif(($IntHomeScore > $IntAwayScore) && ($IntHomePrediction > $IntAwayPrediction) || ($IntHomeScore < $IntAwayScore) && ($IntHomePrediction < $IntAwayPrediction))
```

Comment: That excludes draws that have the wrong values tipped. eg. tip 5:5 when the result is 3:3.

Comment: For draws I can use another elseif like this: 

    //draw
    elseif (($IntHomeScore == $IntAwayScore) != ($IntHomePrediction  == $IntAwayPrediction ))
    {
     $intPoints = 5;
    }